# ASP.Net MVC and IIS 7 using Virtual Directory to a config file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, web-config, virtual-directory, appsettings

I have an MVC application that is shared by many websites in IIS, but each needs it's own app settings.  In my Web.Config, I have the following:

```
<appSettings file="Config/AppSettings.config" />
```

Then, in IIS I set up virtual directories for each site's separate file.

To my astonishment, this did not work, but did when I tried it without using a virtual directory.  Any ideas?

I saw this post [IIS Config file in virtual directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/587537/iis-config-file-in-virtual-directory)

which was very similar, but did not offer the response I was looking for.

I'm also open to other ways to accomplish the same thing; if such a solution exists.

Comment: possible duplicate of [IIS Config file in virtual directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/587537/iis-config-file-in-virtual-directory). Sorry, but asking a duplicate question because the original doesn't offer the response you are looking for won't help. Maybe it's just not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to use a virtual directory (or even files outside of the current website; only the current folder, or a sub-folder) in 'appSettings file=...'.

One possible way to share setting across projects would be to do it at build-time - either by coping it in, or using a Linked File in VS to have it copied to the folder on publish.

If you really need this functionality on the server, you could try (though I can't say how well it would work) a [Junction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point).

Comment: I do believe that's not what I said! But thanks for the downvote! You cannot use virtual directories in the <appSettings file=...> tag.